# Transpose with Sheet Names

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, transpose

I have VBA code which transposes data within a spreadsheet so that it may be fed into another program. The following code needs to execute through a number of Sheets within the Spreadsheet, based on the Sheet name.

The code executes correctly when manually entering the Sheet names, however, now that I am trying to add an array I receive an error when I try to execute the code; the error reads ‘type mismatch’ and occurs on the line with the arrow below.

If anyone can help I would appreciate it! I assume the issue is to do with how the Sheet names are read, however, as a new user of VBA I am having issues resolving the problem:

```
Sub LoopThroughSheets()

Dim Sheets As Variant
Dim Sheet As Variant

Sheets = Array("Sheet4.3")

For Each Sheet In Sheets
    'Code goes here.

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i, k, multiple As Integer
Dim rawrowcount As Long
Dim rawcolcount As Long
    'Define variables for the below-noted code

For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name = "Q_" & Sheets Then <-- <-- <-- <--
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Delete
    End If
Next i
    'Delete Worksheet if already existing for respective tab

With ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
    ws.Name = "Q_" & Sheets
    ws.Range("A1").Value = "Year"
    ws.Range("B1").Value = "Product"
    ws.Range("C1").Value = "Product Type"
    ws.Range("D1").Value = "Cashflow"
End With
    'Insert column headings for Resulting spreadsheet

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("4.3")
    '.Range("I:I").Delete
    .Range("A:A").Delete
    '.Rows(111).Delete
    rawrowcount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A:A")) - WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A1:A10")) - 1
    rawcolcount = .Cells(10, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 2
End With
'Count the number of rows and columns to determine how many the number of iterations
'for the next set of code

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Do not update screen while executing code

For i = 1 To rawcolcount
    multiple = rawrowcount * (i - 1)
    For k = 1 To rawrowcount
        'Sheets("4.3").Activate
        'ActiveSheet.Range("A9").Select
        'Selection.Offset(k + 1, 0).Select
        'Selection.Copy
        'Sheets("Q_" & Sheets).Activate
        'ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
        'Selection.Offset(k + multiple, 0).Select
        'ActiveSheet.Paste
            'Copy and paste Years 1 to 100

        Sheets("4.3").Activate
        ActiveSheet.Range("A9").Select
        Selection.Offset(k + 1, i).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Q_" & Sheets).Activate
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
        Selection.Offset(k + multiple, 3).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
            'Copy and paste the Cashflow for Years 1 to 100 for
            'each Product

    Next k
        'Repeat for each Product Type


    Sheets("4.3").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("A9").Select
    Selection.Offset(2, 0).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Q_" & Sheets).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Offset(multiple + 1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
        'Copy & paste the Year for each respective Cashflow

    'Sheets("Q_" & Sheets).Activate
    'ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    'Selection.Offset(multiple + 1, 1).Value = "Canada Region"
        'Copy & paste Region for the respective Cashflow

    Sheets("4.3").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("A9").Select
    Selection.Offset(1, i).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Q_" & Sheets).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Offset(multiple + 1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
        'Copy & paste the Product for each respective Cashflow

    Sheets("4.3").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("A9").Select
    Selection.Offset(0, i).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Q_" & Sheets).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Offset(multiple + 1, 2).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
        'Copy & paste the Product Type for each respective Cashflow

    'Sheets("4.3").Activate
    'ActiveSheet.Range("B8").Select
    'Selection.Offset(0, i).Select
    'Selection.Copy
    'Sheets("Q_" & Sheets).Activate
    'ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    'Selection.Offset(multiple + 1, 4).Select
    'ActiveSheet.Paste
        'Copy & paste Risk for the respective Cashflow

    ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(multiple + 2, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(multiple + 2, 3)).Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(multiple + 2, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(multiple + 101, 3))
        'Autofill the Region, Product and Product Type for each Cashflow

Next i
    'Repeat for Years 1 to 100

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Do not update screen while executing code

Call Delete
    'Call the next subroutine (Delete)


ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.ClearFormats
    'Clear formatting in Output Worksheet

Set ws = Nothing

Next Sheet
End Sub
```

Comment: `Sheets` is an array, but your comparison is comparing text to text.  You should either set `Sheets = "Sheet4.3"` or set  `= "Q_" & Sheets` to `= "Q_" & Sheets(0)` but looking at your code, I'm not sure if there may be other things you need to review a little more as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking each sheet name in the workbook against the name(s) in your array, you can simply load the names you want to remove into the array and then delete them (using an On Error Resume Next statement to ignore any instances where the Worksheet does not exist).

This has the potential to be more efficient because you will not loop through *every* sheet in the workbook, but only loop through the sheets you want to delete (if they exist already).

Also, stay away from naming variables that coincidence with Excel Object names (like Sheets).

```
Dim aSheets() as Variant
'Dim aSheets() as String 'alternate approach

aSheets = Array("Sheet4.3","Sheet4.4","Sheet4.5") 'extra added as example
'aSheets = Split("Sheet4.3,Sheet4.4,Sheet4.5",",") 'alternate approach

Dim x as Integer
On Error Resume Next ' will ignore instances where sheet is not in workbook
For x = LBound(aSheets) to UBound(aSheets)

    Worksheets("Q_" & aSheets(x)).Delete

Next
On Error GoTo 0 'resets error catch so any errors in further code will appear
```

Comment: Hi Scott, I really like your approach! That had not occurred to me. I will clean up the code to first delete all irrelevant worksheets (as you did above) and then have my script loop through the entire spreadsheet.